# theorem numeration in appendix

Tags: appendix

How to let the theorems display as Theorem A.1, Theorem A.2, etc. in appendix?

Solution

```
\renewcommand*{\thetheorem}{\mbox{\textrm A.\arabic{theorem}}}
```

is not suitable because of wrong link (to the Theorem 1, not Theorem A.1) using `hyperref` package...

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the standard `book` class, without further packages, one solution is to redefine `\@thmcounter` at the time `\appendix` is ​​declared:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
    \pretocmd{\appendix}{\def\@thmcounter#1{\noexpand\Alph{#1}}}{}{}
  \makeatother
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
    \pretocmd{\appendix}{\def\@thmcounter#1{\noexpand\Alph{#1}}}{}{}
  \makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 
\chapter{Lorem}
  See \autoref{thm:2}

  \begin{theorem}\label{thm:1} 
    Hello world!
  \end{theorem}

\appendix

\chapter{Ipsum}
See \autoref{thm:1}  
  \begin{theorem}\label{thm:2}
    Hello world!
  \end{theorem}
 
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]